# How to find all WiFi networks that are not in range?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I am writing an application to display the WiFi network types and status. How do I find all the "not in range" WiFi networks? Is it possible to get the list of all configured (previously seen) WiFi networks that are out of range?

I used the below code to get the result

```
    WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
    if (configs != null) {
        for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                if (result.SSID  == null || result.SSID.length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    if (result.SSID.equals(MyString.removeDoubleQuotes(config.SSID))) {
                        int level = mWifiManager.CalculateSignalLevel(result.level, 4);
                        Log.d("MyApp", Config.SSID + "  " + level);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But if configured network is high in number then it will take long time to execute. Is there any way to optimize this problem? By getting the scanned result of only the configured network.

Answer (score 3):

How about subtracting the wifi networks in range from all wifi networks?

Comment: Yes i think that is the idea, but i don't know the exact API to find the networks are in range in wifiManager. Can you provide some insights on how to find those?

Comment: Sorry for following up late but how can i optimize the above one. Because if configured network is high in number then it will take more time to get the result.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Configured networds are stored on your device, so retrieving them is fast. Slow is to find other networks in range. How long does it take to get all the configured networks?